# Check if a value that can also be null is greater than 4 in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I check if a value that is initialised as null or number is greater than 4 in typescript?
see example.

```
years: number | null;
```

this will give a typescript error "Object is possibly 'null'."

```
(years > 4)
```

Comment: Well it's not wrong... If you did a check before and you are sure this is not null you can do (years! > 4) to tell the ide that it's for sure not a null, otherwise check for null, in general I wouldn't combine the option to have null and a number

Comment: Have you considered the expression: `(years && years > 4)`? Or even `(typeof years === "number" && years > 4)`?

Comment: @CRice Yes, but having to repeat that expression every time is a pain - I think the OP is asking about how to encode a range-limit as a _predicate-type_ - unfortunately TS doesn't support "real" predicate-types but you can use a typedef and a guard-function as a kind-of-predicate-type.

Comment: If we are just trying to avoid repetition, then perhaps Shai's suggestion will be best. JS will convert `null` to `0` in that comparison, so it will work fine even if `years` is `null`. And adding the `!` will prevent typescript from complaining about it.

Comment: @Dai yeah that's exactly what I was asking

Comment: and for @CRice the second suggestion work 
but a bit too lengthy

Comment: @SamuelSharpe See my answer

Comment: @Dai thanks that works, however, would it be bad code if I do something like  `((years || 0) >4)`?

Comment: @SamuelSharpe That's valid code for an arbitrary expression, but you can't use that expression as a type-guard in TypeScript (type-guards aren't as _expressive_ as normal expressions).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're asking how you can express the *static requirement* that a function parameter (or return-value, or class property value) named `x` always satisfies `( x is number && x > 4 ) | null`.

...which is also known as [a Predicate Type](https://wiki.c2.com/?PredicateTypes), [Refinement Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type), or [Dependent Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type).

Unfortunately TypeScript (to my knowledge) doesn't yet support *true* refinement-types or predicate-types (though its flow-analysis capabilities are *almost there*), but you can *almost* get there with a type-def and a type-guard:

```
type NumberGT4OrNull = null | ( number & { _isGT4: never } );

function isNumberGT4OrNull( x: unknown ): x is NumberGT4OrNull {
    if( typeof x === 'number' ) {
        return x > 4;
    }
    return false;
}
```

- The type declaration `type NumberGT4OrNull = null | number;` is too permissive, as it matches the value `1`, for example.
- Making it a *sum type* with a member typed as `never` means that no *literal* value (or any other value) possible within TypeScript or JavaScript can match `NumberGT4OrNull` - at least not without using the custom type-guard `isNumberGT4OrNull`, which prevents accidentally using any value *not* checked by `isNumberGT4OrNull` in a parameter, return-value, or property typed as `NumberGT4OrNull`.

  - ...except for `null`, because in this case, the `null` keyword is outside the sum-type with `never`.

    - But if you want to require even `null` values to be checked then use `type NumberGT4OrNull = ( null | number ) & { _isGT4: never };`.
  - The downside is you can't *not* use `isNumberGT4OrNull`, but this isn't *that big a problem* in the grand scheme of things.

Used like so:

```
function acceptsValue( value: NumberGT4OrNull ): void {
}

//

const userInput = prompt("Enter number");
acceptsValue( userInput ); // Error: userInput is a string

const userInputNumber = parseInt( userInput, 10 );
acceptsValue( userInputNumber ); // Error: userInputNumber is not NumberGT4OrNull

if( isNumberGT4OrNull( userInputNumber ) ) {
    acceptsValue( userInputNumber ); // OK! TSC knows `userInputNumber` is `NumberGT4OrNull`.
}
```

As said above, the use of `never` means a literal value won't match, so the following won't work and will give you errors:

```
acceptsValue( 3 ); // Error
acceptsValue( 4 ); // Error
acceptsValue( 5 ); // Error
acceptsValue( null ); // But this is OK
```

But you can add a (non-exhaustive) set of constant values for convenience if you like:

```
type NumberGT4OrNull = null | ( number & { _isGT4: never } ) | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16;

// So now, this does work:
acceptsValue( 3 ); // Error
acceptsValue( 4 ); // Error
acceptsValue( 5 ); // OK!
acceptsValue( null ); // Also OK

const n = 17;
acceptsValue( n ); // Error
if( isNumberGT4OrNull( n ) ) {
    acceptsValue( n ); // OK!
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFoFwTwBwUwAQDkCuBbARnATgcQCoAsA8tqgDbkIC8CAFAgHYqUIA+T6W2CAlAgDIEAbwQB9AJYBnAoQBcTOADccCAL4BucCABmKRgGMIEgPaME01JhyzSFcgwAeC-QGtGJgO7neCxxalkLhsiOxYqYVAEaIsdBmh4Ex0Ef2o0hAByZmtsDL4RKJii7DgIFGxzfwA+BEItECK1QuiSsoqEHQBDcik4eqawEAB6EaHtPUNjMwROgwM4GAgpADVulDgGJTW4BStuWzJwvgUlEwkAEwKQAdAR7QMzKQgEFF7sAElGGBRn2hhsExoRZ0ABEAFFGBBVNluCD+GwOBkMvVZvNFittgxXjhPt9nrwNAgRggwdgAdgXG9cT8AjMEE9sBJGABze6PZ7Yj5fH57VR-TrYXqfCBYqnciAAGgQAEYAAx8FFzBZLVbkdainHi3k8AlEoYkskmCkvMV47W0jzPbUHezaCRxALW0KHSgarlm4I6-KRBoxVHKjFqjYmzUenIKvUIYgAaQAhAh8ABlADCCHcXkCAANOdSINrM7TM06SC7yJmAHSgG6DO6Df3o1XqhAAVgjxNJ5MrIHrKsxtTb+o7Rq7PcDTYAzAODZ2gA)

Comment: @CRice I found a bug in my answer - the `acceptsValue( userInputNumber );` statement actually compiles fine - I'm seeing how I can make it work correctly, hmm.

Comment: Use a virtual property as the discriminator, this way the value must pass through the type guard before it can be given to `acceptsValue`. EG: `type isNumberGT4OrNull = (number | null) & {_isGT4: never}`.

Answer (score 1):

`years` might be a number, or or might be `null`. And `null > 4` doesn't make any sense.

So before you do that, you have to check to make sure it's not actually `null` first.

```
if (years !== null) {
  const isMoreThanFour = years > 4
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=2#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gTxLNAXPCgK4C2ARiDPAD7EkQQDcAUKwJYBm8AFLvngBCALwiGTAJTwA3q3iJUmeBzQBZJHAAqACygoAYkhI1xAmGngA+eABZWAXyA)

Comment: Could also combine it into a single if statement:
`if (years && years > 4)`. 

For refererence: 
`if (years)` returns `true` if years is not: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, empty string `''`, `0`, or `false`.